# UIGestureRecognizer in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to add `UIGestureRecognizer` to `UITableViewCell`.
When I call `panAction:` in `CustomCell` class, it will work.
But I'd like to call the method in `ViewController` class, and in this case, it will not work.

How do I fix it to work `panAction:`?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    [_tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *nibName = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nibName];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = (CustomCell*)[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nibName];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)setupGesture
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
    CustomCell* cell = (CustomCell*)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}

- (void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint location = [sender translationInView:sender.view];    
    NSLog(@"%f", location);
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:sender.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code posted above, you don't call `setupGesture`. This way your cell won't pick up the gestures. Also, you should just add create and add `panRecognizer` to the cell in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexpath:` like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *nibName = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nibName];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    return cell;
}
```